How can I implement my C# UWP to Flutter Windows Desktop
I have a UWP C# File which handles WiFi Direct Connection (Windows to Android Connection) but I want the UI and frontend to be served from flutter side, but I am unsure how can I implement C# bridging between flutter and C#. If any could give insights to this it would be much appreciated. For now if I could get help with something basic like hello world.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FlutterTEst
{
    public sealed class HelloWorld
    {
        public static string GetMessage()
        {
            return "Hello, World from C#!";
        }
    }
}

This is the code I have on my class.cs, How can i print hello world from C# and give that output to flutter.
Thanks :)
Tried to make a dll but unsure how to get an dll for UWP

Why is this tagged c++?

Eventually I think after I have a proper C# output C++ will have to be the bridge for method callbacks between flutter and C#

It might be easier to call the win32 API directly using package:win32
